# How to achieve this with CSS?

Tags: css

I wouldn't call myself a programmer at all but I do know some basic css. However, I have trouble creating a table that looks something like on this site: https://www.slotsia.com.

What I wish to achieve is that row numbering to the far left together with that corner graphic. I'm sure it's all done with css and the numbering is probably automatic.

I use wordpress and the plugin tablepress to create tables.

I did try to put the following code in the css which achieved the numbering, even if it starts wrong with 0 instead of 1.

```
.tablepress-id-4 { 
    counter-reset: rowNumber; 
} 
.tablepress-id-4 tr:not(:first-child) { 
    counter-increment: rowNumber; 
} 
.tablepress-id-4 tr td:first-child::before { 
    content: counter(rowNumber); 
    min-width: 1em; 
    margin-right: .5em; 
}
```

Also, the larger text doesn't look like normal fonts? I'm thinking it's font awesome or google fonts or something? How to use that?

Thank you

Comment: SO isn't a code-writing service. Please review [ask] and provide a [mcve] of what you've tried with a *specific* question about where you ran into trouble. [Currently it doesn't seem as though you've put in enough research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: Ok, sorry. I''m new to this.

I use wordpress and the plugin tablepress to create tables. I did try to put the following code in the css which achieved the numbering, even if it starts wrong with 0 instead of 1.

.tablepress-id-4 {
 counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

.tablepress-id-4 tr:not(:first-child) {
 counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

.tablepress-id-4 tr td:first-child::before {
 content: counter(rowNumber);
 min-width: 1em;
 margin-right: .5em;
}

Comment: Please use the edit button rather than attempting to post important information via comments. That said, if you inspected the source of the page you linked you'd have your answer on how it was implemented.

Comment: Ok, sorry I give up. I'm obviously not a good enough programmer to be posting here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle demonstrating to accomplish that index thing in the cell : https://jsfiddle.net/59wfkzgs/2/

## HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="index">1</span>
            ABC
        </td>
        <td>
            ABC
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="index">2</span>
            ABC
        </td>
        <td>DEF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="index">3</span>
            ABC
        </td>
        <td>DEF</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

## CSS

```
table, tr, td {
    font-family:"Segoe UI";

    padding:20px;

    border:solid 1px black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

td {
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    min-width:150px;
}

.index {
    position:absolute;

    top:-2px;
    left:-2px;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;

    border:solid 1px black;
    border-radius:0 0 100px 0;

    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

You are able to do -almost- everything you want in a table's cells, so you can stylish it in any way you want to. Do not fear of doing so :).

Hope it helps.

Dylan